# How can I open a new tab which is NOT active with HTML or Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to open a url with new tab, but it should be not active.

```
<a href="example.com" target='_blank' rel="noopener noreferrer">Example</a>
```

I tried above code, but it opens new tab which is active.
I don't want a browser to focus on the new tab.
Is there any good way to open a new tab still focusing the previous tab?

Comment: Browsers have worked quite hard over the years to *prevent* websites opening things secretly in the background.

Comment: The user has many options to do that (middle-click, ctrl+click, right-click and then "open in new tab"). All of these normally open in the background. So, you just need to show a message to the user explaining how to do it if they want it that way. (You can't force it, because the user needs to be aware that their action just opened another page, and when it's in the background, they may not notice.)